# mongodb collection cleanup older than 12 hrs

Tags: mongodb

Someone please suggest the command to cleanup mongodb collection events older than 12 hrs.

I need to configure this as part of cronjob, and will be executing at every 12.00 PM and 12.00 AM.

Comment: Have a look at [TTL indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Comment: What are you struggling with? Show us what you've tried please.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to store creation date and time in your documents. Create an additional field, if you do not have it. Having this field i collection, you have two options:

1. Either running a job with cron, that will remove all documents older than 12 hr. Smthing like `db.collection.remove({"createdAt" : {$gt : Date.now() - 43200000}})`
2. Create an TTL index for this field, that will automatically do all the cool things. `db.collection.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { "expireAfterSeconds": 43200 } )`

I would prefer the second solution.